# Android: How to capture or redirect the logs from LogCat to a file using ECLIPSE IDE

Tags: android, logging

In Android, How to capture or redirect the logs from LogCat to a file using ECLIPSE IDE. 
I dont want to use command prompt option. As i haven't configured it . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the logcat view, to the right of the 'delete log' icon, is a pulldown (View menu), it brings up:

[image]

You can select the portion of log that you want, then use the "Export selection as text" option

Comment: The problem is since i have so much logging n it keeps updating i wont be able to select it during the runtime

Comment: At runtime bcoz of threads the logging screen gets updated very fast and after sometime i'm able to see only 2 lines in logcat.

Answer (score 7):

See [logcat | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html).

Can be redirected to file from the command prompt. Use `adb logcat -f <filename>`, or in Linux it will be better `adb logcat | tee <filename>`.

Also, you can capture the time stamp as well with
`adb logcat -v time -f <filename>`, or in Linux it will be `adb logcat -v time | tee <filename>`.

Comment: yeah, except the stupid busybox or whatever crap that comes with android apparently doesn't have the tee command.

Answer (score 0):

**use freopen to redirect stdout and stderr**

the native code below works for me.

```
// cachedir is get from java code 'Context.getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()'
auto fullpath = cachedir + "/log";  
freopen(fullpath.c_str(),"w",stderr);

std::cerr << "hello, world\n";  // will write to file located at external storage
```