# How to redirect logcat output?

Tags: android, logcat

Is there a way to redirect the logcat's output towards an InputStream or something like that? I'm thinking of something in the lines of how you can redirect the stderr in C.
I want to do it so its redirected when my app starts and everything that happends get dumped to a file.

Comment: take a look here http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/reading-logs-programatically with proper permission you are able to read logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I found is to use `System.setErr`. I allows you to easily redirect the error output to a file.

Example:

```
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new File("<file_path>"))
```

Comment: This will only capture output printed to `System.err` (and potentially `System.out` if you redirect it in the same manner). However, the output will not include the prefix Android ads to each line (timestamp, PID, TID etc.), and anything logged through the `Log` class will also not be redirected here.

Comment: how do you redirect the Log to a file, run some crashes with Log.e(), and then read the file?

Answer (score 7):

If you can connect the device for debugging, you can this from the command line

```
$ adb logcat > textfile.txt
```

Comment: How long does this last? I mean, if I reboot the device, will it still be redirected?

Comment: No, It will redirect as long as 'adb' is active. On reboot, 'adb' protocol does not work, hence it will not be redirected at that time.

Comment: @rodkarom No, adb will disconnect when you reboot but you can start again or send to a different file when you reboot.

Comment: and if the device is unplugged from the USB? is that logcat will turned off as well? @spatulamania

Answer (score 1):

The only redirecting possibilites of LogCat output are documentend [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715492/android-how-to-capture-or-redirect-the-logs-from-logcat-to-a-file-using-eclipse).

It is not possible to reuse the LogCat output in your app itself. You can however, [export it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359692/how-to-redirect-my-log-output-from-logcat-to-the-sd-card-on-an-android-device) like you ask.

Answer (score 0):

to filter logcat just from your app try this:

```
        int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
        File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/logcat.txt");
        Log.d("zzz","outputFile: " + outputFile);
        try {
            String command = "logcat | grep " + pid + " > " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d("zzz","command: " + command);
            Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
            os.write((command + "\n").getBytes("ASCII"));
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
```

Comment: There may be an easier way: run `logcat` without `su` and without granting the `READ_LOGS` permission to the app, which constrains the entries returned to the caller’s UID (i.e. your app, including earlier instances and subprocesses). This seems to vary between Android distributions, though. Otherwise, `logcat` also has the `-e` option to filter by regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, this is what I used and it seems to create and log to the logcat.txt file (located in the app directory) whether the app is being debugged or run directly from the tablet.  (Sidenote: For some reason the directory doesn't refresh or show up in file explorer until I stop the app and reconnect the device.)  (thanks for the help from the previous contributors)

```
   located in utilities...
     val publicDirectory = globalContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)
                publicDirectoryName = publicDirectory?.toString() + "/"


        fun redirectLogcatToFile() {
        try {
            val filename =
                File(Utilities.publicDirectoryName + "logcat.txt")
            filename.createNewFile()
            val cmd = "logcat -v time -f " + filename.getAbsolutePath() +" -s " + logcatTag
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)
        } catch (ex: Exception ) {
            Utilities.toastOnAnyThread("Utilities.redirectLogcatToFile: " + ex.message)
        }
    }
    
    fun Log( message : String ){
        Log.i(logcatTag, message )
    }
```